# Trying to use json load with txt file

Tags: python, json, text

`import json 
f=open("99_jiayi.txt",'r',encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
a=json.load(f)
f.close()`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD3M5.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP0oW.png

I tried to turn the text file into a list in order to analyze the data

I used the "json load" and it worked on another file which is written in the same mode

But when i want to use it on another file it comes out the error

i searched google for a lot of time but still cant get the ans

Hope someone can help me with this question

i have some problem to express my thought with eng so if anyone cant understand what i am typing plz let me know tks!!

Comment: plz click the link above the article i screenshoted my error

Comment: Also, it would be much better to post real/example data/code than images. One thing I would be curios about is if there is actually a comma between the elements in your input JSON, you can't tell in your screenshot as it is off the side of the image.

Comment: If you can, just dump your JSON into an online JSON validator to verify it isn't just a data issue. The error you are receiving suggests it is just malformed JSON.

Comment: Use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to upload your JSON file to. Then post the URL here. We can then see your JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

The error message points to "1":NR, which does not look like valid JSON, so it seems like a valid error.

Edit: try putting all NR within quotes.